# Javamail Android: cannot seem to connect

Tags: android, sockets, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying Javamail on android to read mails via imap.
here is my code but it doesn't work. it gives error 
 request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

plz post a working code for android javamail Imap session

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Click","Click");
    new read().execute();

}
public class read extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String url = null;
          String protocol = "imap";
          String host = "localhost";
          String user = "user";
          String password = "passowrd";

          try {
           // Get a Properties object
           Properties props = System.getProperties();

           // Get a Session object
           Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

           // Get a Store object
           Store store = null;
           if (url != null) {
            URLName urln = new URLName(url);
            store = session.getStore(urln);
            store.connect();
           } else {
            if (protocol != null)
             store = session.getStore(protocol);
            else
             store = session.getStore();

            // Connect
            if (host != null || user != null || password != null)
             store.connect(host, user, password);
            else
             store.connect();
           }

           // Open the Folder
           String mbox = "INBOX";
           Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
           if (folder == null) {
            System.out.println("No default folder");
            System.exit(1);
           }

           folder = folder.getFolder(mbox);
           Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
           Log.v("unread", ""+folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

}
          catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
          return null;
```

Comment: You're connecting to localhost and running on a mobile phone. I doubt you'll find an IMAP server there.

Comment: I dont think thats the case... as the send email program is working without any prob..

Comment: Does the "send email program" also do ...connect("localhost", ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Yow, that shouldn't happen!  Are you trying to connect to an IPv6 host on a device that only supports IPv4, or vice versa?  If you turn on JavaMail session debugging, what does the debug output show?